# How to place a link on the middle of a div in height?

Tags: html, css

How do I place the link Refresh on the middle in height of the div nav_bar?

```
<div id="nav_bar">
<a class="nav" id="refresh" href="#">Refresh</a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for more help
http://jsfiddle.net/axuxT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The easiest way is to set `line-height` to be the same height as the container. This will fail if you ever add more text that spans more than one line (dependent on your circumstances, you could avoid this with `white-space: nowrap`).
- You could also add top and bottom padding, e.g. `padding: 30px 0`.
- You could add `display: table-cell` and then `vertical-align: middle`. The only problem with this one however is that it is not supported <= IE8.

Comment: @Sparky672: Yeah, 'spose I should mention that.

Comment: +1, good options.  one note: options 1 and 2 only work for a container that has a fixed height.  See the second part of my answer for a solution that will scale with the parent container.  (of course, every different solution has its own unique drawbacks... you'll have to pick the one that best fits your needs).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the parent div (eg: `35px`), and you know it won't change, then you can just set `line-height: 35px;` on the link, and the browser's inline formatting will do the rest.  I updated your fiddle to show this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/axuxT/1/.

---

**Update**

If you need the container div to be able to change size, it's a bit more complex.  Here's an update to your fiddle that shows this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/axuxT/3/.  Note that, in this case, the content needs to be display:block, with a known height. It also requires some additional markup - an additional wrapper div, and a floating spacer div.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like an easy thing to do, right? but there's no way that's correct, you just have to you `margin-top` or `vertical-align` or `position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -half-the-element-height-px'`.

I hate CSS.

Comment: Since you hate CSS, it would have been better not to answer than post a bunch of incomplete fragments.